# Creating a linux user with limited privileges for ssh tunnelling

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ssh-tunneling, authorization

I am following [this post](http://chxo.com/be2/20040511_5667.html) to create ssh tunnel to mysql. The details description of my application scenario is given in my other [SOQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22086849/ssh-tunnelling-from-php-to-multiple-nodes).

I exactly followed these steps to create a user:

```
useradd -s /bin/false myuser
mkdir /home/myuser/.ssh
touch /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
chown -R myuser:myuser /home/myuser/.ssh
chmod 755 /home/myuser/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

It did not work for me. Not even able to ssh into remote server.

Given the post very old I am looking for sane way to create a limited privileges user which 
only connect to mysql and nothing else. I am testing this under ubuntu.

The other issue with this is to test the ssh connection from my system. So how I will create authorization keys for a system ( my local machine) which does not have a static IP. However the network in which I am working have a static IP. Is it possible to create authorization keys for that IP ?

**Edit**

Re-tested with two vagrant ubuntu instances, it works using ubuntu user with password , but unable to connect with `myuser` and `rsa key` as created in given article.

**SSH KEY**

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
Generating public/private rsa key pair.
Enter file in which to save the key (/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa): 
/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa already exists.
Overwrite (y/n)? y
Enter passphrase (empty for no passphrase): 
Enter same passphrase again: 
Your identification has been saved in /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.
Your public key has been saved in /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
```

**Upload to server**

```
scp /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa.pub vagrant@192.168.33.55:.
vagrant@192.168.33.55's password: 
id_rsa.pub              100%
```

**Append RSA key to ghost user ssh keys**

```
ubuntu@DEV:~ cat id_rsa.pub >> /home/ghost/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**SSH LOG**

```
vagrant@precise64:~$ ssh -fNg -vvv -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 ghost@192.168.33.55 
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.33.55 [192.168.33.55] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.33.55" from file "/home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-256-96,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha2-512-96,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-md5
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 11:5d:55:29:8a:77:d8:08:b4:00:9b:a3:61:93:fe:e5
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "192.168.33.55" from file "/home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type ECDSA in file /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '192.168.33.55' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/vagrant/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f446fe9ada0)
debug2: key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/vagrant/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred: ,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
ghost@192.168.33.55's password:
```

**192.168.33.55 /etc/ssh/sshd_config**

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
#AuthorizedKeysFile %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

**192.168.33.55 SSHD LOGS**

```
tail /var/log/auth.log -n 100

Feb 28 10:15:42 precise64 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 10:15:53 precise64 sshd[2154]: Failed password for ghost from 192.168.33.31 port 52350 ssh2
Feb 28 10:15:53 precise64 sshd[2154]: Failed password for ghost from 192.168.33.31 port 52350 ssh2
Feb 28 10:15:53 precise64 sshd[2154]: Connection closed by 192.168.33.31 [preauth]
Feb 28 10:17:01 precise64 CRON[2157]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Feb 28 10:17:01 precise64 CRON[2157]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
```

Comment: There is nothing about adding the public ssh keys to the `/home/myuser/.ssh/authorized_keys` file ?!

Comment: I have added the ssh keys as describe in the article. Created ssh keys on the client side and uploaded to serverside and appended the keys to newly created user `myuser`'s authorized_keys file. But still no luck : `vagrant@precise64:~$ ssh -fNg -L 3307:127.0.0.1:3306 myuser@192.168.33.55`
`myuser@192.168.33.55's password: `. It should not prompt for password given the ssh keys

Comment: could you add the log of your loging attempt with ssh but add the switch `-vvv` to your ssh command

Comment: @Kiwy, please see logs , My assumption is that the rsa public key generated by command `ssh-keygen -t rsa` does not add proper host name bcz as I cat the key file I see it ending with `vagrant@precise64` instead of the instance ip address which is `192.168.33.31` in this case. The question is how to generate rsa keys for specifics user@ip address

Comment: Just edit it. `user@ip ` is an optional information field.

Comment: @sakhunzai the key is not linked to a host if I remeber correctly but what's important is how you import it in the known host what I find strange here is the absence of answer from you server once the key is loaded

Comment: @Kiwy please see the complete log, it was me who truncated logs sorry .

Comment: What does the SSHD log on the server say?

Comment: @JennyD please guide me how to check

Comment: What about the sshd configuration (usually in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`) ? In particular `RSAAuthentication`, `PubkeyAuthentication` and `AuthorizedKeysFile` configuration key values.

Comment: @sakhunzai It depends on your syslog setup. Start with `grep ssh /var/log/secure` - if you don't find anything, grep in `/var/log/auth.log` or `/var/log/messages`.

Comment: please see the edits. I added logs they are not showing any useful stuff. But i `sshd_config` file `AuthorizedKeysFile` seems to be commented out

Comment: what are the authorization on file authorized key ?

Comment: `-rw------- 1 ghost   ghost    400 Feb 28 10:04 authorized_keys`

Answer (score 1):

In search of restarting the sshd after updating `AuthorizedKeysFile` in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I got [here with exact same error](https://serverfault.com/questions/135151/how-do-i-restart-ssh-or-sshd-on-ubuntu#135170)

Which guided me to install:

```
   sudo apt-get install openssh-server
   sudo initctl reload-configuration
   sudo service ssh start
```

After that I checked ssh logs

```
tail /var/log/auth.log -n 100 
  Feb 28 11:11:40 precise64 sshd[2826]: Server listening on :: port 22.
Feb 28 11:11:43 precise64 sshd[2827]: Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory /home/ghost
```

Got it :)

```
sudo chown ghost:ghost -R /home/ghost
```

And now I am getting the two instances connected and able to connect to mysql through tunnel

One strange thing is that if I comment out  `#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys` in sshd_config ,I am still able to connect .

Thank you all for helping me in right direction

Comment: By default, AuthorizedKeysFile  uses that value.  If you don't specify a value it falls back on the default.